# .addOnCompleteListener not working for FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()

Tags: android

I am new to android development. Before posting this question, I have checked if same issue had been posted and had a solution. I couldn't find and so posting here.

I am trying to get FCM token and using the below piece of code.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                                    return;
                                }

                                // Get new Instance ID token
                                String token = task.getResult().getToken();

                                // Log and toast

                                Log.d(TAG, token);
                            }
                        });
```

I am not getting **any** error. However method onComplete is not getting executed.

Could please someone help me on this. I have been trying this for couple of days.

Please note that, as per few suggestions on SOF, I followed .on SuccessfullListener also. But the same issue with that as well.

I am using the below things.

```
Manifest:
<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

App level Gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Project Gradle:
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: I may have the same problem. Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Did you add your google-services.json file to the app?

Answer (score 0):

addOnCompleteListener runs on the background thread so it's not clear when it will be done.
I advice using onNewToken(String token) in your custom FirebaseMessagingService :

```
public class FireBaseCustomReciver extends FirebaseMessagingService {
  private static final String TAG = "aaa";


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  // ...
}


@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
  Log.e("aaa", "Refreshed token: " + token);

}
}
```